# Problem when submitting job using XGrid API

Tags: cocoa, distributed-computing

I'm attempting to submit a job using the XGrid API. I've opened a connection, and that seems to work ok, although it sometimes doesn't open, but when I do the following:

```
 jobSubmissionMonitor = [controller performSubmitJobActionWithJobSpecification:jobSpecification gridIdentifier: nil];
    [jobSubmissionMonitor addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"outcome" options:0 context:NULL];
```

My observeValueForKeyPath is never called. Any idea what that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. Turns out that Xgrid does not seem to work well when you've got the garbage collector enabled.